# Can notes on line items be updated on checkout?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Currently, a user has to click update on each line item to save changes to quantity or a note. The quantity might make sense to the user as it updates the price, but a user could assume that the note would just need to be filled out.

Wondering if there's a simple way to allow the user to fill out notes without clicking update and have them save.

Answer (score 5):

I use ajax autosave to achieve this, and ajax update the cart in the background (for notes, but also pretty much everything else).

I essentially use the recipe from:
from https://github.com/geniuscarrier/autoSave/

In the callback function that is called after the autosave event, I post the to the update cart controller.  The JSON object that comes back from an ajax request is quite complete and let's your update your cart page / totals etc from there.

Personally I hate non dynamic carts with update buttons, so I have ajaxed all cart operations, including qty changes, removals, line item and order notes etc.